# Expand JTable size to fill JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

I'm trying to create a program that displays a table with data on it, called a Time Log program. I'm having trouble expanding a Jtable to fill a JPanel, since it's currently looking like this:

[image: Huge white gap]
You can see the huge white gap below the table, but I want the rows to be evenly distributed among the space.

Below is my code.

This is a class I call TimeLogApplication, which has main method and creates a JFrame.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* Create a new frame */
    JFrame guiFrame = new JFrame("Time Log Program");

    /* Set size of the frame */
    guiFrame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

    /* Add the panel */
    guiFrame.add(new TimeLogPanel());

    /* Exit normally on closing the window */
    guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    /* Show the frame */
    guiFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The JFrame calls TimeLogPanel class that creates a JPanel. This panel has a Border Layout. The table is added to the center panel, which also has Border Layout.

```
public TimeLogPanel() {

    // Set layout, add table panel
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(20, 20));
    add(tablePanel);

    // Create table panel and set layout
    tablePanel = new JPanel();
    tablePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // Create a new table with row and column number
    table = new JTable(rowNum, colNum); 
    table.setShowGrid(true);
    table.setGridColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Set a raised border
    table.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));

    // Add table to table panel
    tablePanel.add(table);      
}
```

I have tried to get the panel height but since it is not created until the frame is created, the panel height is zero.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

UPDATE:
I tried out the suggestions and it worked beautifully (adding ComponentListener to the JPanel that holds the JTable). This is what I did:

```
tablePanel.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                tablePanelSize = tablePanel.getHeight();
                table.setRowHeight(tablePanel.getHeight()/rowNum); //RowNum is the number of rows
        }

        // Below methods are not used but must be there, as a requirement when adding a listener
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {          
        }

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {              
        }

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {             
        }           
    });
```

Comment: Instead of `guiFrame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);` use `guiFrame.pack()` but only do so after you've established the content of the UI.  Also, you will find that `JTable` would prefer to be wrapped in a `JScrollPane`

Comment: He apparently wants it the other way around (fit the table's row size to the panel).

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks! That works too. I tried it, but the frame becomes seriously small :(

Comment: @Van Put the `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes a pretty scroll appeared. And for some mysterious reason, my columns are all labelled (A, B, C and D) !

Comment: @Van That's because you don't provide any column names - See [How to use tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to add a `ComponentListener` (`componentResized` event),  calculate the row height and then call `JTable.setRowHeight`.

Comment: Thanks! Should I add ComponentListener to the table or to the panel that holds the table?

Comment: Hm. I'm guessing adding it to the JPanel should do the trick.

Comment: You don't need to check the event source BTW. Nice to hear it works :) Please accept the answer, I am greedy for rep, lol

Comment: Suree. You deserve the reputation :D

Comment: Oh, sorry madame :)

Comment: This serves as an additional contribution to @StefanReich's response. Add a JPanel and set its layout to BorderLayout.